# Finding logged in user email Buddypress

Tags: email, buddypress

How do I retrieve and display the email of the user who id currently logged in. I am using Buddypress.

```
<?php
global $bp;

 function bp_member_user_email() {
echo $bp->bp_get_member_user_email();
}

$bp->bp_member_user_email();

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

One:

```
global $bp;
echo $bp->loggedin_user->userdata->user_email;
```

Two:

```
global $bp;
echo bp_core_get_user_email($bp->loggedin_user->id);
```

Three:

```
echo bp_core_get_user_email(get_current_user_id());
```